# How can I exclude .* directories from rsync but include the .vnc directory?

Tags: rsync

It seems that a combination of `--exclude '.*'` and `--include '.vnc'` does not work:

```
rsync -vvrR --recursive --exclude Downloads --exclude '.*'  --include '.vnc/' "pi@$host:{/home/pi,/etc/systemd/system}" $dir
```

The .vnc directory is not synced

```
[sender] hiding file /home/pi/.bash_history because of pattern .*
[sender] hiding directory /home/pi/.ssh because of pattern .*
....
[sender] hiding directory /home/pi/.vnc because of pattern .*
```

Comment: put `--exclude` after `--include`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of `--include` and `--exclude` is important for `rsync`.

See `man rsync` => `FILTER RULES` section:

> As  the  list  of  files/directories to transfer is built, rsync checks
> each name to be transferred against the list  of  include/exclude  pat‐
> terns in turn, and **the first matching pattern is acted on**:  if it is an
> exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern
> then  that  filename  is  not skipped; if no matching pattern is found,
> then the filename is not skipped.

(accentuation by me)

That means for you:

```
rsync -vvrR --recursive --exclude Downloads --include '.vnc/' --exclude '.*' "pi@$host:{/home/pi,/etc/systemd/system}" "$dir"
```